# Ubuntu /tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: Read-only file system

Tags: server, apache2

I have a bewildering issue on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04 droplet. I shutdown my droplet to take a snapshot but then on turning on services wouldn't come up.

I get the error below when trying to restart.

```
* Restarting web server apache2 mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: Read-only file system
/etc/init.d/apache2: 91: /etc/init.d/apache2: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
[fail]
* The apache2 configtest failed.
```

I had the following issue below and even opened a ticket that was never resolved so I moved my droplet to AWS and left the current ones which didn't have a problem. This is my 4 droplet with the same issue.

I use Symfony 3, WKHTML for PDF generation, Sentora Control Panel, and recently have run Selenium for javascript even though the previous three servers didn't have an issue. I pretty much haven't changed anything from default OS installation and Sentora config.

Have you ever experienced this issue before and how did you solved it?

I tried all the fsck commands and answers in similar posts here last three times with no luck

Edit

I have found the solution, I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/hardening-ubuntu-server/) to harden my server so issue is brought about by the fstab entries below:

```
# Written by the DigitalOcean build process

LABEL=DOROOT   /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro    0 1
proc           /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid          0 0
tmpfs          /run/shm        tmpfs   ro,noexec,nosuid             0 0
/usr/tmpDSK    /tmp            tmpfs   loop,nosuid,noexec,rw        0 0
```

How would I secure /tmp without encountering the errors on boot?

Comment: Updated question with new information

Comment: That is an odd set of mount options. First they make a loop device, then mount it using type `tmpfs` (!) - I'd say the author doesn't really know what they're doing. `tmpfs` is a special filesystem that resides in memory (including swap), so mounting a loop device as `tmpfs` doesn't make any sense at all. Further, `tmpfs` is limited to about half of RAM in size, by default, so if the intention was to limit usage of `/tmp`, just mounting `tmpfs` is enough. I'd take that entire article with a (large) pinch of salt.

Comment: Thanks, have you seen any online that's worth following?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `sudo mount -a` after reboot, thats it.